# Compute a list of rounded proportions

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, finance

Required:

```
[10,20,-30] -> [1,2,-3]
[19,-14,15] -> [2,-1,2]
[-1.09,-0.92,0.02] -> [-109,-92,2]
[501.6545,-1857.1,897.543] -> [5,-19,9]
```

The number closest to zero in each input set should be a single digit number in the output. The proportions must be kept approximately constant, rounding errors accepted.

Context: Converting the number of shares of securities to buy from a model to round lots of 100 using the smallest orders possible.

I can brute force this in a non-pythonic way but I'm looking for pointers on Python functions to use. My background is Java.

Comment: Is it acceptable for the "single digit number" to always be 1? Then you should be able to solve this, easily.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa The smallest digit cannot be 1 because the proportion would change drastically and the output must be whole numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[-1.09,-0.92,-0.02] -> [-109,-92,-2]`?

Comment: @user8408080 good catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you would use `numpy` for such calculations. I would suggest an algorithm like this:

```
def process(array):
    order_of_magnitude = np.floor(np.log10(np.min(np.abs(array))))
    return np.round(array*10**(-order_of_magnitude))
```

Explanation:

1. Find the order of magnitude of the smallest element in the array (regardless of sign).
2. Scale every element (or up) according to this.
3. Round the result

You will need to install `numpy` for this. For example with `pip` or via your linux distribution.

Turn your lists into numpy arrays like this:

```
array = np.array(your_list)
```

Comment: I posted code based on your in a new answer that fulfills the requirement. Python balked at raising the array to a float exponent so I converted it to an nparray. I also converted the answer to integers. Thanks for you help, I would never have figured the Pythonic solution out.

Comment: @KevinRethwisch that is interesting, as I didn't receive any warning complaining about rasing an array to a float exponent. Which numpy and python versions are you on? Anyways, I'm glad I could help!

Comment: It is strange since exponents can be decimal numbers. Here's my versions:
Python 2.7.16
Numpy 1.16.2

Comment: @KevinRethwisch Oh well those are fairly old versions. I would *strongly* advise you to not use Python 2 anymore, especially as you seem to be a python beginner. This Software is not supported anymore and only installed on some Linux distributions for backwards compatibility reasons. It can be quite irritating on -- for example -- Debian-based systems, that call python2, when you execute `python` in the terminal. In that case, just type `python3` and you will be working with the supported python version. Also, if you are using pip, then -- on those distributions -- you will have to use `pip3`.

Comment: I use Arch, btw

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring your examples, I implemented the requirement

> The number closest to zero in each input set should be a single digit number in the output. The proportions must be kept approximately constant, rounding errors accepted.

This algorithm normalizes the data by the absolute value of the value closest to zero, and multiplies that result by 9 to keep the smallest number one-digit, thus minimizing the subsequent rounding error.

```
def normalize(l):
    import numpy as np
    m = np.min(np.abs(l))
    return np.round(l / m * 9).astype(int)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I'm not sure why you multiplied by 9 but it yields incorrect results. Removing the 9 makes the proportion minimum 1, as you suggested in a comment, but also yields incorrect results.

Comment: The algorithm you used to generate the examples yields huge errors, just check `[19, -14, 15]` resulting in `[2, -1, 2]`. This will give much better results.

Comment: Huge errors are generated either way. You example as written yields

[  9  18 -27]
[ 9 -9  9]
[-490 -414    9]
[  9 -33  16]

Without multiplying by 9 we get

[ 1  2 -3]
[ 1 -1  1]
[-54 -46   1]
[ 1 -4  2]

Both are incorrect.

Comment: That's exactly the reason why we multiply by 9 in the first place, to _minimize_ the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer based on @user8408080 answer.

```
import numpy as np
def process(array):
    order_of_magnitude = np.floor(np.log10(np.min(np.abs(array)))).astype(int).item()
    return np.round(np.asarray(array)*10**(-order_of_magnitude)).astype(int)
```